# Error in reading .csv file in python

Tags: python-3.x, csv, file-handling

```
def __init__(self):
        self.aBasePath = os.getcwd()
        self.DataStorePath = self.aBasePath+"/Data.csv"
        try:
            self.fileDataSet=open(self.DataStorePath)
            print("Opened training dataset.")
        except:
            print("Unable to open training dataset.")
            self.fileDataSet = None

def readFile(self, filePointer=None):
        if filePointer is None:
            filePointer = self.fileDataSet

        try:
            count=0
            print("Started to read")
            with filePointer as f:
               for line in f:
                  print("Started to read")
                  if count==0:
                    print("Started to read")
                    count+=1
                    continue
                  print("Started to read")
                  print(line)

            filePointer.close()
        except:
            print("Unable to read")
```

error:

> Opened training dataset. 
>  Started to read 
>  Unable to read

Above code works good with 15 lines of data but the given error comes if number of lines in input is increased. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what error occurs if you remove your try/catch statement from readFile?

Comment: Just allow the exception to be raised so you can actually see what the problem is and begin to debug it. 

    `except Exception as e: raise e`

Comment: @DragonBobZ found the exception and solved it.